# proper way to compare two timestamp fields in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Say I have two timestamp type columns timestamp_column1 and timestamp_column2
I want to compare if timestamp_column1 is greater than timestamp_column2. 
How do I compare these two timestamps ? Does comparison operators work properly with timestamp on Oracle?

timestamp_column1 > timestamp_column2

Is this correct??
Or do I have to wrap them in some function to compare them with each other
like to_timestamp(timestamp_column1) >  to_timestamp(timestamp_column2)
?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the "timestamp" columns are truly using one of the date or timestamp data types, then yes the usual relational operators will work.

The only time you need to wrap a timestamp in a function is if it's erroneously stored as a string, or if you want to manipulate it in some way such as truncating it to the hour, day, week, month, year or other less discreet unit of time.